# Threading still takes a very long time

Tags: python, multithreading, shopify, python-multithreading

I have made a script which constructs a checkout URL for shopify websites. This is done by appending each unique product 'variant' ID in the checkout URL and then opening the said URL in a webbrowser. To find the variant ID, i need to parse the website's sitemap to obtain the ID, which I am currenly doing in seperate threads for each product i am parsing, however with each thread added the time it takes increases by quite a lot (nearly one second).

Why is this the case? Shouldn't it take around the same time since each thread basically does the same exact thing?

For reference, one thread takes around 2.0s, two threads 2.8s and three threads around 3.8s

Here is my code:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import threading

sitemap2 = 'https://deadstock.ca/sitemap_products_1.xml'
atc_url = 'https://deadstock.ca/cart/'

# CHANGE SITEMAP TO THE CORRECT ONE (THE SITE YOU ARE SCRAPING)

variant_list = []


def add_to_cart(keywords, size):
    init = time.time()
    # Initialize session
    product_url = ''
    parse_session = requests.Session()
    response = parse_session.get(sitemap2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    variant_id = 0

    # Find Item
    for urls in soup.find_all('url'):
        for images in urls.find_all('image:image'):
            if all(i in images.find('image:title').text.lower() for i in keywords):
                now = time.time()
                product_name = images.find('image:title').text
                print('FOUND: ' + product_name + ' - ' + str(format(now-init, '.3g')) + 's')
                product_url = urls.find("loc").text

    if product_url != '':
        response1 = parse_session.get(product_url+".xml")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response1.content,'lxml')
        for variants in soup.find_all('variant'):
            if size in variants.find('title').text.lower():
                variant_id = variants.find('id', type='integer').text
                atc_link = str(variant_id)+':1'
                print(atc_link)
                variant_list.append(atc_link)


    try:
        print("PARSED PRODUCT: " + product_name)

    except UnboundLocalError:
        print("Retrying")
        add_to_cart(keywords, size)


def open_checkout():
    url = 'https://deadstock.ca/cart/'
    for var in variant_list:
        url = url + var + ','
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)




# When initializing a new thread, only change the keywords in the args, and make sure you start and join the thread.
# Change sitemap in scraper.py to your websites' sitemap

# If the script finds multiple items, the first item will be opened so please try to be very specific yet accurate.

def main():
    print("Starting Script")
    init = time.time()

    try:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=add_to_cart, args=(['alltimers','relations','t-shirt','white'],'s',))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=add_to_cart, args=(['alltimers', 'relations', 'maroon'],'s',))
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=add_to_cart, args=(['brain', 'dead','melter'], 's',))
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t3.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        t3.join()
        print(variant_list)
        open_checkout()
    except:
        print("Product not found / not yet live. Retrying..")
        main()

    print("Time taken: " + str(time.time()-init))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Indent your code properly for readers

Comment: @donkopotamus apologies - fixed

Comment: First regarding multithreading, you will always get an overhead when using several threads (creation time, context switching), which won't make it the exact same time as the linear case. Second, notice that in your code the time you compute is also including the `open_checkout` call which can hardly be considered a constant (except if your bandwidth is **always** constant). Lastly Python's implementation, because of the GIL, greatly slows a multithreading implementation compared to one of another language (see https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... one thread takes around 2.0s, two threads 2.8s and three threads around 3.8s

Regarding your example code, you are counting​ the **sum** of all `threads`.
As #asettouf pointed out, there is a **overhead**, mean you have to pay for it.
But I assume, doing this 3 tasks `threaded` will be faster as doing it one after the other.